# Tile with a drawable background exceeds height limit

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a tile with some "shadow" and rounded corners using the following layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/background" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/activity_background" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="3px" android:right="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It's used as a background for dynamically loaded views that are not activity layouts, and thus do not cover the whole screen (notifications, for example).
Here's a layout that uses this tile:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to use a drawable PNG as the background of the layout. I tried to put it directly as the background of the layout `android:background="@drawable/blob_gradient"` but then the first view (aka first notification) covers the whole screen. I also tried to use the tile with `android:drawable="@drawable/blob_gradient"` in its last item, but same results.

I'm sure that the solution is simple, and I probably approach the subject with the wrong attitude. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply use a 9 patch. Shadow included.

Comment: I tried it, made a 9-patch with the stretch lines all along, but it ended with the same results. 
Just to mention, the background picture is pretty big, but I don't think that it should have any effect when you mention specific dp, right?

Comment: 9 patches work fine, if correctly used. See this [page](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) for a complete introduction